# Oracle SQL find substring plus 2 characters in column and remove the substring

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv

I have a column which contains initial string with comma separated values like:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-136=6,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9013=100,TEST-9=4
```

And I need replace or regexp_replace SQL to remove substring TEST-136=2, so that I will have result string:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9013=100,TEST-9=4
```

The following SQL removes only e.g. TEST-136 from the column string, but not the "=6" part:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = REPLACE(mycolumn, 'TEST-136', '');
```

Moreover, if possible I would like to even remove 2 or more specific substrings that I want, meaning both TEST-136=6 and TEST-9013=100, so to have result string as:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9=4
```

Note that TEST-136=6, TEST-9013=100 can be at random positions of the column string, NOT specific.

Also, TEST-136=6 or TEST-9013=100 can be at end of string, so in that case want to also remove the comma that will exist after removing the substring.  For example:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9=4,TEST-9013=100
```

should become:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9=4
```

and NOT:

```
TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9=4,
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `replace()`?

```
replace(replace(mycolumn, 'TEST-136=6', ''), 'TEST-9013=100', '')
```

If you want this to be generalized:

```
regexp_replace(mycolumn, '(TEST-136|TEST-9013)=[0-9]*', '', 1, 0)
```

If you want this to be generalized and to remove the next comma:

```
regexp_replace(mycolumn, '(TEST-136|TEST-9013)=[0-9]*,?', '', 1, 0)
```

Comment: Latest regexp_replace SQL appears to do the job best way! Only issue is that at some cases e.g. the TEST-9013 or TEST-APN-136 are at the end of the mycolumn string and at those cases there is a comma left at the end of string like, for example: TEST-10=5,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,      So, can SQL change to take into account also comma left at end of column string so that it will be removed at that case?   Thank you.

Comment: @Kostas75 . . . I would suggest that you use `trim()`.  This gets tricky, because it is the comma *before* the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```
SELECT
    col,
    TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ',?TEST-(136|9013)=[0-9]+,?', ',')) AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

The regex replacement logic here is to find `TEST-\d+=\d+` for certain values, along with an optional leading/trailing comma.  We then replace with just a single comma.  There is an edge case here should the replacement target be the first or last entry in the CSV string.  In that case, a leading/trailing comma might be left behind.  So we trim off such commas.

Note that the *best* answer here might be to tell you to stop storing CSV in your SQL tables.  Doing string manipulations like this to update your table is very costly, and not the intended use of a database.  Instead, consider putting each CSV value onto a separate row.